# css property behaving weirdly -- hidding html element but leaving a big blank space element occuping the same space of the hidden element in website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm having a problem with a css element on my website.

I cannot determine why the css is behaving like this > https://www.platiniumhost.com/hosting.php... checked everything here and it should work but it is not...

The problem:

If you scroll down the page you will see a big blank space... you can use control(-)  key  in https://www.platiniumhost.com/hosting.php in order to reduce zoom  to -25% to see all the blank space correctly see here:  [image: Here you can see the big blank space (i zoomed out -25% so you could see it correctly)]... so then...

If you check source code with "Right click> inspect element" and use control+F (to find something)
use "popup" in the search bar

you will find the property `<div class="modal-wrapper" id="popup">`

i will explain how it works, it is a simple div using the:

```
#popup {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

property.. if you uncheck it :

```
visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
```

you will see the big blank space will be replaced by the hidden element... with whis[image: See here]

the question here is... how do i get rid of that white big blank space? what i want to do is to when hidden it does not show the big white space... the problem is here

```
<div class="modal-wrapper" id="popup">
```

because if you in the element inspector change the "id=popup" for any value, for example 0, the big blank space will be deleted and replaced for the hidden element which is occupying the same space of the white blank page...

i checked the code and i don't know what is happening or why it is happening,

here is the Javascript element just in case you need it:

[scripts.min.js](https://www.platiniumhost.com/templates/PlatiniumHost750/js/scripts.min.js?v=1837a1)

also, there is a function in the main js called

"popupWindow" i do not know if it does have to do something with the above staement, however since the js file is minified, you could use control(c) / control(v)  (copy/paste)

https://beautifier.io > beautify javascript and control(c) / control(v)  (copy/paste) into your editor and check it, however i will post the function here so you do not have the need to check the source file and do the exposed above...

```
function popupWindow(t, e, n, i, r) {
    var o = (screen.width - n) / 2,
        a = (screen.height - i) / 2;
    o < 0 && (o = 0), a < 0 && (a = 0);
    var s = "height=" + i + ",";
    s += "width=" + n + ",", s += "top=" + a + ",", s += "left=" + o + ",", s += r, win = window.open(t, e, s), win.window.focus()
}
```

however have not found any anomally or something weird.... i do not know why the css is behaving like this...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Stolen from [google search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=visibility+hidden+vs+display+none): display:none means that the tag in question will not appear on the page at all (although you can still interact with it through the dom). There will be no space allocated for it between the other tags. visibility:hidden means that unlike display:none, the tag is not visible, but space is allocated for it on the page

Comment: Thank you nikki, how do i upvote your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:none;`
instead of `visiblity:hidden`